# I deleted Ubuntu and accidentally deleted Grub with it. Other OS's aren't booting now. How do I fix this?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I was running a dual-booted Ubuntu/Windows 8.1 PC. I deleted my Ubuntu partition so I could install Arch, but in doing so I also accidentally messed up Grub and deleted my Windows EFI partition. I spent some time trying to restore the EFI partition, but I'm wondering if I could fix all of this by reinstalling Grub. Is reinstalling Ubuntu the easiest way to fix this? I can't reformat the drive because I have important work there that I can't lose.

I'm at school right now so I won't be able to post any logs until around 3:30 CST. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: My problem extends beyond deleting Ubuntu. I accidentally messed up my windows filesystem and now it won't boot. It starts up and says there is no OS. I believe the best way to fix this would be to reinstall Grub but I need some confirmation of this.

Comment: have yo tried this [question171722](http://askubuntu.com/questions/171722/cant-boot-to-windows-anymore-after-removing-grub-on-a-netbook)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Restoring Grub will not fix Windows issues. And grub just chain loads to the Windows boot files in the ESP - efi system partition, so those files must exist. Normally if  Windows files deleted you can use your Windows repair flash drive or installer to repair/replace them. And if UEFI, you must have the ESP as a FAT32 formatted partition and with boot flag if creating with gparted.

Comment: @oldfred I've been trying to restore the efi partition. My issue is whenever I try to add boot files there is an error about the files not being able to transfer (I'll find the specific error when I get home). I've been attempting a repair with my windows  8.1 install disk through the command line. From the forums I've read if I can fix that boot partition then it should work, but I can't fix the partition.

Comment: You can try chkdsk on the FAT32 partition if you are in Windows or `sudo fsck -t vfat /dev/sda1` if in Ubuntu. If sda2 change command to correct partition. If neither work you can backup, delete, recreate with gparted as FAT32 and add boot flag to make it the ESP again. Then restore all efi boot folders.

Comment: @oldfred is this a valid method for restoring the efi partition? I can get to the part where you repair the boot record, but when I run (sorry, I don't know how to format code and I'm on mobile) cd /d v:\efi\microsoft\boot it returns that the system cannot find the specified path. Additionally when I list the volumes the efi volume is marked as hidden. http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2013/12/how-to-repair-the-efi-bootloader-in-windows-8/

Comment: Best then to see details, post link from this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score 1):

Install Ubuntu again using bootable USB.

Check this [link](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/) or [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180023/can-i-install-grub-on-an-usb-and-make-it-a-rescue-disk)

Answer (score 0):

Plug in a windows bootable pendrive or CD and then select the repair after you click the next then go to troubleshoot and then there will be an option for choosing command, go to command and type this: bootrec.exe/fixmbr press enter then it will show successful  and then type : exit then start the  windows.... Hope this works, cause mind does for the same problem i faced.